# how to add menu on top of image in html

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My code is in ASP.Net mvc4 . in this only label is coming not data.

```
<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Leader.Name)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
<!--     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Leader.Name)    --->

     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Leader.Name  )
</div>
```

Comment: still the question title is so different from the actual question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Bootstrap responsive UI...

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=bootstrap&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEUQjBAwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.github.com%2Fbootstrap%2Fcomponents.html&ei=Zfn0ULnWN8btrAegsoHoCQ&usg=AFQjCNEGD-rO2TzedFvBGlLrxLrPVxbjQA&bvm=bv.41018144,d.bmk

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following..

if you only want to display then use `@Model.Leader.Name` and if you want to allow user to change this value use `@Html.TextBoxFor(`

```
<div class="display-label">
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Leader.Name)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
 @Model.Leader.Name
</div>
<div class="display-field">
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Leader.Name)
</div>
```

Hope this helps !